# Windows Azure Mobile Service C# Backend - App_Data

Tags: windows, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using windows azure mobile service with the .net runtime.
I am uploading an xml file with web deploy which resides in my app_data directory.
Executing locally this works fine

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/consultants.xml"));
```

However on the server i get the info:

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\MobileServicesDotNet\1.0.303\App_Data\consultants.xml'

Do you have any idea? I think the file is copied somewhere else, but how can i get the path?

Best
laurin

Comment: Did you find the answer yet?

Comment: No i think there is No answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file is most likely at the following location:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\consultants.xml
```

There is a web based diagnostics tool for Azure called Kudu which is helpful for scenarios like these. This blog post has instructions on how to login and use Kudu with your Azure instance, [Using KUDU with Windows Azure Web Sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx).